# Parse for second element of a comma delimted list

Tags: regex

As an example I have a line of text:

```
61024221,ballanty,2,0,$102,,34,12/22/2011 09:08,Reliable
```

I want to extract the 2nd element `ballanty` and the fifth element `$102`.

Can someone guide me perhaps?

Wanting a regex for this. There will be no comma within fields. (actually doing this in uBot).

Comment: Which programming language? And, you probably should use a CSV parser.

Comment: Will your CSV files have commas within the fields, eg. `"123,213",abc,...` ?

Comment: sorry to add I wanted the regex for this. there will be no comma within fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split is certainly the best way, but if you really need a regex:

```
/^[^,]*,([^,]*),[^$]*(\$[^,]*),/
```

group 1 will contain `ballanty`

group 2 will contain `$102`

**regex explanation:**

```
/             : regex delimiter
  ^           : start of line
    [^,]*     : any number of char that is not a comma
    ,         : a comma
    (         : start group 1
      [^,]*   : any number of char that is not a comma
    )         : end group 1
    ,         : a comma
    [^$]*     : any number of char that is not $
    (         : start group 2
      \$[^,]* : $ char followed by any number of char that is not a comma
    )         : end group 2
    ,         : a comma
/             : regex delimiter
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in `awk`. My example is split onto two lines for clarity.

```
echo "61024221,ballanty,2,0,$102,,34,12/22/2011 09:08,Reliable" | \
awk -F, '{ print $2, $5 }'
```

The `-F,` option sets the comma to be the field delimiter, and then the part inside the curly braces prints the second and fifth fields.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use regex?

If you are using javascript, you can divide the line into an array and extract accordingly:

```
var a = '61024221,ballanty,2,0,$102,,34,12/22/2011 09:08,Reliable';
var b = a.split(',');
alert(b[1]);
alert(b[4]);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/phMtJ/

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with Ubot you do not need any regular expression - you can use the following code:

```
set(#text,"61024221,ballanty,2,0,$102,,34,12/22/2011 09:08,Reliable","Global")
clear list(%list from text)
add list to list(%list from text,$list from text(#text,","),"Don\'t Delete","Global")
alert($list item(%list from text,1))
alert($list item(%list from text,4))
```

Comment: The OP clearly asked for "wanting a regex" solution. Your solution has nothing to do with regex.